# How to check the jcr publication status programatically on Publish from Author in CQ 5/AEM?

Tags: aem

I am building a workflow component where I would like to check the publication status of a jcr component on Publish instance from Author

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Please add more details to the question. What have you tried till now, where you are facing issues and so on..

Comment: I would like to the status of a jcr content is delivered to Publisher or not from author after activation

Comment: Are you saying you want a workflow which checks and returns the replication status on a jcr path ? By the way for your information you have a replication queue on the replication agent, also you may check replication logs as to know what all is been sent for activation and what is the replication status of it.